# changePage without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

`mobile.changePage('UI/Demo/home.html');`

Without using AJAX, how to call this? Blackberrry 5 does not support AJAX for this. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's ugly, but you could load the requested call at the same time (assuming no $.get or $.post) and hide the page until the user needs access.

Comment: @SableFoste will you please show some code. I did not get your point.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this javascript redirection i use in my webapps:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function redirect(url)
{
window.location = url;
}

</script>
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply But I can't use window .location because I am facing this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624939/back-button-is-not-working-in-jquery-mobile) issue

Comment: i had this same problem in my jquery mobile webapp, and it solved usig the redirecction i sugest.

"data-rel='back'" doesnt works well on jquerymobile because when yout redirect on jquerymobile it doesnt navigates to another page, it actualy "overrides" the current page.

To redirect back in my webapp i store in a session variable the page where i came from and i use the back button as this:

<a onclick="navegar('<?php echo $href_back ?>')"  data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Volver</a>

where "navegar" is the function i posted before

Comment: yes using that I am able to navigate to next page but on that next page back button is not working as I mention in above link.

Comment: If i use session variable  it works perfectly but if I press hardware back button then it again goes to all pages where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

```
window.open(url)
```

Comment: window.open(url) navigate to page but same issue for back button

Comment: try adding this to your back button code - data-ajax="false" and then try using window.open or location again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no data passing without cookies is necessary, something like:

The HTML:

```
<div id="startsinvisible">
  ... Stuff to "load" on update...
</div>
<div id="firstload">
  ... First visible webpage stuff ...
  <input id="changepage" type="submit" value="Load New Page" />
</div>
```

the jQuery:

```
$('#changepage').on("click", function(e){
  $('#firstload').remove();
  $('#startsinvisible').show();
}
```

You can add as many `<div>` as you need and hide/remove/show with logic.

This is really more of an AJAX simulation than actual call.  As I said in my earlier comments, it's ugly, but could get the job done since you were looking for suggestions.  Of course, this doesn't work if you *actually* need AJAX, and need to send data back and forth.